# Python Selenium "driver.page_source" call from website server or local content

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, scrape

I am very new to Python, it`s about 6 months, I have a very basic question.

Where is the source of "driver.page_source", dose it retrieve and read from the local content of the website, I mean whatever server has already sent to the local page, or every time it will send a request or call directly to the website server.

I want to scrape live data so I need to do "driver.page_source" every minute, while I don't want to disturb the website server by sending too many requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.page_source` retrieves the HTML of the url you passed on `driver.get(url)`.

It gets the same code as seen on your browser when you click `Inspect Element`.

If you want specific elements and not the whole page though, you should loop up Xpaths and use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_expression)`.

Comment: Thanks  @GentBajko  for your quick response, Yes I know it, my question is every time I load driver.page_source it asks from URL server or it read from URL content which has downloaded already on my computer?

Comment: @Alexpy the code has already been downloaded once you use driver.get()

Comment: Thank you  @gent-bajko for clarification